# Getting familiar with .NET - What's the best way?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a friend of mine who owns his own software consulting business. Most of the stuff his employees work on is .NET related development. He's been out of actual development for many years, and has been focused on building his business. He asked me the best way to get familiar with the whole .NET platform and development under .NET. Is anyone aware of a video training series, or something similar, that's designed to get someone up to speed on all aspects of .NET?

Comment: Practice. Jump into a project elbows deep.

Comment: @Joel - He doesn't want to jump back into programming. He just wants to be able to talk intelligently about it (.NET).

Comment: my comment still stands though. If he wants to talk intelligently about .Net, he's going to need to get into it and do it. I'm not suggesting a massive project like a CMS or accounting application. He should get the buzzwords he's interested in (WPF, WCF, MVC, etc) and write a (Hello World + 1) style app for that technology. It will at least raise the questions he needs to be asking, and those can be answered largely by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that he doesn't have to cover *all* of .NET, but a great way to get up to speed with both C# and a significant part of the .NET framework is the [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800963?green=12748717798&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596800963.IP). It assumes some programming experience and covers a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is the obligatory "port another project into .NET" answer.

Comment: It's hard to jump right into it when you feel like you have no idea where to start but it only gets easier.

Comment: True :) but with so much reading material it's hard to know where to start with that too! A practical exercise, developer pairing, or looking at example projects is best in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the first step is to read a book which covers different parts of .Net Framework. [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491) is one possible book as it covers different technologies such as WPF, WCF, Linq, Ef, Asp.Net. They are not discussed in depth but is a good resource for getting familiar with current technology stack.

Also, I would recommend actually developing in .Net as is many knowledge comes from the actually doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, maybe your friend could sit in on any code reviews, design sessions or even perform pair programming with the other developers once he gets a basic understanding of things on his own.  I suppose this could be difficult in a consulting business vs. regular development shop though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the books and blogs which will be mentioned, I always recommend people start learning with something **practical**.

When I'm teaching I make up simple exercises broken down into chunks like build a basic database, try simple things like displaying the data, filter the data using drop down, add auto postbacks and update panels, updating the data in the DB. It doesn't take long to get an overview of the  basic concepts, techniques and tools when presented with examples. And then it's down to experimentation, imagination, and research!

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy Visual Studio and an MSDN membership - in case its a startup there maybe various options to reduce this cost (Bizspark/Websitespark)
2. Go through common walkthroughs - areas to go through are Winforms, Asp.net, Asp.net Ajax in that order. Can go through WCF, Silverlight and other framework options later.
3. Search the web for 'Azure trial' - supposedly, there is a one month free pass available. Dont know if this is real, but if it is, take it and deploy simple applications on the cloud - learn what Windows Azure and Sql azure are all about. After a while can learn about Appfabric messaging platform as well.

After this, start deep-diving into any areas of the technology depending on project needs.

Comment: Of course if it is a capability overview that is required vs a developer overview, then focus on various MSDN articles - but walkthroughs with simple projects can be really powerful if you dont mind the handson approach.

Answer (score 0):

[Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/)

[ASP.NET getting started](http://www.asp.net/get-started)

[Dimecast](http://dimecasts.net/)

[DNR TV](http://www.dnrtv.com/)

Answer (score 0):

more than reading any book what made get started with .NET was doing projects. Start building a web site if you want to learn ASP.NET, you get to learn C# and VB as well like this. Just by reading a book each chapter would take lot of time. Initially you will do lot of mistakes and you will frequently get the dreaded yellow error page. The more mistakes you make, the merrier. My experience with .NET is limited to ASP.NET, C#,LINQ, web services, SQL Server 2008. But it took less than 20 days for me to get to know about all these stuff. Now I am trying to do WPF, WCF, Silverlight projects. IF I read any .NET book now, it wouldn't take much time for me to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

I realy suggest to use a step by step teach your self book. They are good for beginners and have some practices maybe something from SAMS publishing like 
[Teach yourself c# in 21 days](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672320711)